# How to setup XUnit testing in Jetbrains Rider for ASP.NET CORE 2?

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, rider

I have a problem with testing in Rider using XUnit.

Basically, I have a solution with two project - one is the rest-api-app, the second is rest-api-app-test. Both are the exact .net core versions, are in the same solution, but I have no idea where to set the reference from rest-api-app-test project to the rest-api-app. When I was adding testing project to the main solution, I didnt see any option to set reference to the tested project.

With that being said, I can't use 'using rest-api-app' namespace in the test project.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix that; I am almost sure it was some kind of framework bug.

**tl;dr**
Just try to use classes and methods from desired namespace, InteliSense should suggest to import it, like normally it does.

What I have done (steps):

1. Restarted few time Rider IDE (**I think it was relevant**).
2. Although, I didn't have 'Using rest_api' (.NET CORE didnt recognize it at all, neither InteliSense did any sugestions to fix it), I have tried to use some classes & methods from the 'rest_api' namespace and viola! InteliSense suggested to import rest_api namespace :D

I am still curious why this bug occured, nevertheless, I am happy it has passed.